# Uncaught ReferenceError: resize_cnt is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following challenge on my website.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: resize_cnt is not defined
>       at loop (main.js:204)
>       at init.js:201

I've got embedded code on my website that opens modal window and the error only occurs on pages that have that modal included. That embedded code is a designstudio plugin where customer can design their own space and I've added woocommerce functions that collects the samples that customer requested and add them to the woocommerce basket.

```js
// this is the main loop, always running
function loop() {
    if (ao.sys.resize_enable == 1) {
    if (ao.sys.loading == 0) {
        ao.sys.global_loader.deact();
    } else {
        ao.sys.global_loader.act();
    }
    refresh_pos_size();
    if (typeof (appli_loop) == "function") {
        appli_loop();
    }
    if (typeof (cust_loop) == "function") {
        cust_loop();
    }

    if (typeof (ao.init.orientation_enable) != 'undefined'
        && ao.init.orientation_enable == 1) {
        detect_orientation();
    }
    if (ao.sys.rendering == 0
        && ($(window).height() != ao.sys.current_h || $(window).width() != ao.sys.current_w)) {
        ao.sys.current_w = $(window).width();
        ao.sys.current_h = $(window).height();
        resize_done = 1;
        resize_cnt = 0;
        if (current_room_id > -1) {
        set_display();
        }
    } else {
        resize_cnt++;   /** here is where the error occurs **/
    }
    if ((resize_done == 1) && (resize_cnt > 10)
        && (ao.sys.resize_enable == 1)) {
        if (ao.sys.comp_active == 1) {
        // btt_left_comp_func();
        }
        if (typeof (appli_loop_after_resize) == "function") {
        appli_loop_after_resize();
        }
        if (typeof (cust_loop_after_resize) == "function") {
        cust_loop_after_resize();
        }

        resize_done = 0;
        resize_cnt = 0;
        if (editor_mode != 0) {
        scale_to_view();
```

```js
function init_app() {
    ao.sys.init_cnt++;
    // alert(ao.sys.init_cnt);
    debug.log('init_app: ' + ao.sys.init_cnt + ' / 13');

    switch (ao.sys.init_cnt) {
    case 1:
    load_user();
    break;
    case 2:
    if (ao.cfg.phonegap == 1) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("country_" + ao.cfg.app_version) != null) {
        ao.sys.current_country = localStorage.getItem("country_"
            + ao.cfg.app_version);
        ao.cfg.language = localStorage.getItem("language_"
            + ao.cfg.app_version);
        }
        checkConnection();
        init_db();
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    load_language();
    break;
    case 4:
    if (typeof load_catlist == 'function') {
        load_catlist();
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 5:
    load_room_list();
    break;
    case 6:
    if (typeof load_prodlist_egger_vds_online == 'function') {
        load_prodlist_egger_vds_online();
    } else {
        if (typeof load_prodlist == 'function') {
        load_prodlist();
        } else {
        init_app();
        }
    }
    break;
    case 7:
    init_application();
    break;
    case 8:
    if ((ao.cfg.phonegap == 1)
        && (localStorage.getItem("country_" + ao.cfg.app_version) == null)) {
        debug.log('load_settings call');

        load_settings();
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 9:
    if (ao.cfg.phonegap == 1) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("country_" + ao.cfg.app_version) != localStorage
            .getItem("old_country_" + ao.cfg.app_version)) {
        localStorage.setItem("old_country_" + ao.cfg.app_version,
            ao.sys.current_country);
        debug.log('init_db2 call');
        init_db2();
        } else {
        init_app();
        }
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 10:
    init_startscreen();
    break;
    case 11:
    if (typeof init_appli == 'function') {
        init_appli();
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 12:
    if (typeof init_cust == 'function') {
        init_cust();
    } else {
        init_app();
    }
    break;
    case 13:
    ao.sys.loading = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        loop();
    }, 40);
    if (ao.sys.phonegap == 1) {
        if ((ao.sys.device_plattform == "ios")
            && (ao.sys.device_type == 'phone')) {
        window.setTimeout("check_iphone_landscape()", 150);
        }
    }
    if (ao.sys.phonegap == 1) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("country") == null) {
        load_settings();
        }
    }
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
}
```

Any ideas, solutions?

Comment: Part of loop function is missing. Can you update your question ?

Comment: No where in this code does `resize_cnt` get accessed where it could be undefined. Can you post your entire loop function up to and including line 204?

Comment: well where do you declare `resize_cnt`? In the line you highlight with the error, it's incrementing it, but the only place I see where a value is set is a few lines above, in the other branch of the `if` clause. I would assume from this code that `resize_cnt` is declared and initialised outside the loop (since you don't use `var` or `let` to declare it in the code you've shared), but without seeing where that is then it's hard to help. Either you've genuinely not declared/initialised the variable anywhere outside (in which case you should), or if you have it's some kind of scope issue.

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry, tagged the wrong Robin. ;)

Comment: @RobinKitlinski Why was the answer unaccepted, did you discover something new?

Comment: So I've realised that the actual loop happens on the other website that host the whole plugin. Basically, I've got embedded code in a modal iframe that runs an application within it. Wonder if I should get back to guys who gave us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `resize_cnt++;` with

```
if(typeof resize_cnt == 'undefined') { var resize_cnt = 0; }
resize_cnt++;
```

That'll solve your immediate error but you will run into this error elsewhere in your code because you haven't actually declared resize_cnt; anywhere.

**Edit:** Now that I can see your code, just set `var resize_cnt = 0;` right at the start of your script outside of any functions to give it global scope.

For best practice I'd probably recommend a recursive call on loop(); where you pass in the resize count, place this right at the end of your function and controlled by a setTimeout there.